# Having trouble inserting data to mysql datetimepicker

Tags: vb.net, datetime, datetimepicker

How do you insert data into the database using `datetimepicker` in `VB.NET`? I tried to convert it using:
`Format(name_of_the_datetimepicker.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd")` in my `SQL` statement but I don't know where did I go wrong.

Here is my code:

```
    Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
    Public Class frmMain
    Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles       MyBase.Load

    If Not conn Is Nothing Then
        conn.Close()
    End If

    conn = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=" & Server & ";user id=" & UserName & ";password=" & PassWord & ";database=" & DatabaseName & ";")

    Try
        conn.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try


    End Sub

    Private Sub btn_save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_save.Click
    Dim cmdSave As MySqlCommand
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "INSERT INTO (rental_date, inventory_id, customer_id, return_date, staff_id) VALUES ('" & Format(dt_picker_rental_date.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "', '" & txt_inventory_id.Text & "', '" & txt_customer_id.Text & "', '" & Format(dt_picker_return_date.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "', '" & txt_staff_id.Text & "')"


   Try
        cmdSave = New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
        cmdSave.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MsgBox("Success!")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: No matter how you format it, `databases` has its own formatting (that is if the datatype of the field is in `datetime`). What do you want to achieve here btw?

Comment: You don't insert data into a database using a `DateTimePicker`.  You use a `DateTimePicker` to allow the user to select a date and you get a `DateTime` value from that.  What you then do with that `DateTime` is nothing to do with the `DateTimePicker`.  Likewise, you insert `DateTime` values into a database the same way as you insert any other user input: using parameters.  Where the `DateTime` value or other data comes from is irrelevant.  Learn how to use parameters and your problem goes away.

Answer (score 1):

DO NOT use string concatenation to insert data into SQL code.  ALWAYS use parameters.  Parameters maintains all data in binary form so format is never an issue.  More importantly, you are protected from SQL injection.  Using a date, that could look like this:

```
Dim command As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO MyTable (DateColumn) VALUES (@DateColumn)", connection)

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateColumn", myDateTimePicker.Value)
```

If you want to insert just the date without the time then use `Value.Date` instead of just `Value`.

More info on ADO.NET parameters here:

http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It may help you.

cmd.Parameters.Add("date", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value